# Is there anyway to Encrypt and Decrypt data without the need of storing the IV or Key into the database?

Tags: c#, asp.net, encryption

I am a beginner to ASP.Net and I task to do a project assign by my school that requires me to code a strong encryption system such as AES. However, my supervisor does not allow me to store the key and IV into the database. Is there anyway of doing such action?

Comment: are you using asp.net core?

Comment: @OrcusZ nope sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, as you are working on `Asp.net` application you can use `AppSettings` section of `web.config` file to save key.

e.g.

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="Key" value="dcsdUBYBYB66767"/>
</appSettings>
```

You can get this key in your code while encryption/decryption

```
string key = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Key"];
```